# Cannot automatically push commits from script

Tags: linux, bash, git, github, ssh

I used the following script (autoupdate.sh) to update my git repository automatically using SSH whenever I make a change to the local repository in raspberry pi 3B.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATADIR="/home/pi/data"
cd $DATADIR

if [[ -n $(git status -s) ]]; then
    echo "Changed found. Pushing changes..."
    git add -A && git commit -m "$1: Update files" && git push origin main
else
    echo "No changes found. Skip pushing."
fi
```

Then I call a script `measurement.sh` that calls the above script whenever the internet is connected ( I used 4G dongle USB). Something like

```
...    
cd ~/data; bash autoupdate.sh $DATE
...
```

However, when I run `sudo bash measurement.sh` it encountered the errors (It has made a commit but not push). Without sudo it works fine.

```
Permission denied(public key)
...
```

I checked from GitHub document https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey by regenerating the ssh key as well as verified the public key but it did not solve at all. When I pushed commits in a separate terminal it works fines so I do not think the issue relates to the SSH key. I doubt that to run the script successfully it with sudo, the SSH keygen must also be generated with sudo at first.

What could be the reasons for it?

Comment: `sudo`, damn it!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4592122/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34917354/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git+ssh+sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Without sudo it works fine.

So why use `sudo` in the first place.
As commented, using `sudo` alone means using commands as `root`.
At least, a `sudo -u <auser>` would means the `~` in `cd ~/data` would be resolved by the appropriate `/home/auser`, instead of `/root`.

Comment: hello since I need to write to some log files that its owner is root. However, I can change the owner of those log files to current user now it can be written.

Comment: @CoffeePlease Changing the ownership would be easier indeed.